# Can i do a calculation in two text boxes and get the result in an other one

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

i am new to programming and i am programming my first project and i want to know can i do a calculation in two text boxes and get the result to another one
And thank you guys

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk


def add(x, y):
    return x+y


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('340x275+50+50')
root.title('Calculator')  
root.resizable(True, True)
root.iconbitmap("C://123//
icon.ico")

num_1 = Label(root, 
text="First number :")
num_1.grid(row=1, column=1)
num_2 = Label(root, 
text="Second number :")
num_2.grid(row=1, column=3)

textBox1 = Text(root, 
height=2, width=10)
textBox1.grid(row=1, column=2)
input1 = textBox1.get("1.0", 
END)

textBox2 = Text(root, 
height=2, width=10)
textBox2.grid(row=1, column=4)
input2 = textBox2.get("1.0", 
END)

textBox_result = Text(root, 
height=2, width=40)
textBox_result.grid(row=3, 
column=2)

btn_add = Button(root, 
text="+", command=add(input1, 
input2))
btn_add.grid(row=2, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [mre]. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Replaced TKinter to tkinter and also fix this root.iconbitmap("C://123//icon.ico") and also icon is missing

Comment: Used tk.Entry to enter number. Not tk.Text. Also you cannot use this textBox2.get.

Comment: I would think you would benefit from using `Entry` instead of the text box? are you sure that you are trying to accomplish this with the appropriate widget?  It can be done, but using an entry would make more sense to me.  Why wouldn't you use the `Entry` widget instead?

Comment: I will use entry and what change will it make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As newbie tutorial. Try this;

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Sum Two Numbers With GUI Using Python Source Code")
width = 400
height = 280
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
y = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width, height, x, y))
root.resizable(0, 0)

#==============================METHODS========================================
def calculate():
    if not num1.get() and not num2.get():
        print("Please enter a number")
    else:
        res=int(num1.get())+int(num2.get())
        lbl_text.config(text = "The answer is %d" % (res))
        num1.set=""
        num2.set=""

#==============================FRAMES=========================================
Top = Frame(root, bd=2,  relief=RIDGE)
Top.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
Form = Frame(root, height=200)
Form.pack(side=TOP, pady=20)

#==============================LABELS=========================================
lbl_title = Label(Top, text = "Sum Two Numbers With GUI Using Python Source Code", font=('arial', 12))
lbl_title.pack(fill=X)
lbl_num1 = Label(Form, text = "Number 1:", font=('arial', 14), bd=15)
lbl_num1.grid(row=0, sticky="e")
lbl_num2 = Label(Form, text = "Number 2:", font=('arial', 14), bd=15)
lbl_num2.grid(row=1, sticky="e")
lbl_text = Label(Form)
lbl_text.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)

#==============================ENTRY WIDGETS==================================
num1 = Entry(Form, font=(14))
num1.grid(row=0, column=1)
num2 = Entry(Form, font=(14))
num2.grid(row=1, column=1)

#==============================BUTTON WIDGETS=================================
btn_calculate = Button(Form, text="Calculate", width=45, command=calculate)
btn_calculate.grid(pady=25, row=3, columnspan=2)
```

**Another one easy for you**.

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

def findsum(l3, num1, num2):
    n1 = int(num1.get())
    n2 = int(num2.get())
    n3 = n1 + n2
    l3.config(text="Result = %d" % n3)
    return


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Xiith.com")
root.geometry("700x500")

number1 = tk.StringVar()
number2 = tk.StringVar()

l1 = tk.Label(root, text="Enter 1st number").place(x=20, y=60)
l2 = tk.Label(root, text="Enter 2nd number").place(x=20, y=120)
t1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=number1).place(x=200, y=60)
t2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=number2).place(x=200, y=120)

labelResult = tk.Label(root)
labelResult.place(x=250, y=200)

findsum = partial(findsum, labelResult, number1, number2)

b1 = tk.Button(root, text="ADD", command=findsum).place(x=200, y=300)
b2 = tk.Button(root, text="Cancel", command=root.destroy).place(x=250, y=300)

root.mainloop()
```